# Using MKMapView with kml files

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, kml

Just wondering whats the best way to approach this ?

I've looked around for source code to gain an understanding of how this is done. But there is very little out there

Any advice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Apple has samplecode for this. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/KMLViewer/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 1):

Just for info, the default "maps" application supports (basic) display of kml files if you give URL to a kml file on the web.
You can open it from your application using `openURL` for UIApplication and give the URL to the KML file as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Cant use kml files directly with MKMapView:

Use NSXMLParser , and parser (probably title, latitude, longitude).

Comment: Why not? Apple says that you can! See below link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/KMLViewer/Introduction/Intro.html